# Why the writes including multiple racks are costly in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

This content was present on [HDFS documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hdfs_design.html). I cannot understand the reason of last line. According to me in case of more number of racks we can write in parallel on each racks. which will decrease the total time to write. Even it says the cost of writes increases as we need to transfer the data to multiple racks. But in any case we would be transferring data to racks.

Please explain me where I am wrong?

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hdfs_design.html

> The NameNode determines the rack id each DataNode belongs to via the
>   process outlined in Hadoop Rack Awareness. A simple but non-optimal
>   policy is to place replicas on unique racks. This prevents losing data
>   when an entire rack fails and allows use of bandwidth from multiple
>   racks when reading data. This policy evenly distributes replicas in
>   the cluster which makes it easy to balance load on component failure.
>   **However, this policy increases the cost of writes because a write needs to transfer blocks to multiple racks.**

Comment: If you want to replicate data to another rack for fault tolerance (for the case that the complete rack becomes disconnected) you need to transfer the data to another rack which is obviously slower than local or rack-local writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement that you've bolded is meant to convey the **cost** of network hops.  There is an implicit assumption that each cabinet has a top of rack switch that provides connectivity *exclusively* to servers within that rack.

If you were to adopt the "simple" policy of placing each replica to a unique rack, then you are invoking a 2+ hop network copy for each block in this scheme.  This is "non-optimal" compared to the recommended policy of one local-rack replica and another off-rack replica, where there is only one 2+ hop copy, and one 1 hop copy.

Again, this recommendation only holds true in a network topology with **top of rack switching**.  If you were to have some other, flatter network topology, this would be irrelevant.